# Does NSFileManager's moveItemAtPath:toPath:error method load the file being moved into memory?

Tags: ios, sqlite, memory, core-data, nsfilemanager

I move each user's .sqlite database to a different directory in my latest app update. I was using the Core Data method `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error`, and some users' apps were shutting down because of the excessive amount of memory used. So I am reverting to NSFileManager's `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error` method. I don't believe that that loads the database into memory the same way that `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error` does, but I am concerned that moving a very large database could still present the same memory issues. I could use some advice - does anyone know for sure if a file is or is not loaded into memory when it is moved? Is there a way to move a VERY large file in a way that is respectful of device memory? Is there a better method than `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error` available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that moving with NSFileManager should only change the linking in the file system and would not load anything into memory.  But if you really want to know *for sure*, don't trust an answer that you get on Stack Overflow, test it yourself, in your app!  While running your app under Xcode, click the *Debug Navigator*, then the *Show Debug Gauges* tool, then *Memory*.  It looks very pretty.

[image]

Then test one of your file moves and verify that there is no memory spike.